# Oppening csv file with ruby in Ubuntu not working

Tags: ruby, csv, ubuntu

I am creating a CSV file from a txt file in ruby and then I want to open it to parse it.
In windows it works fine but in Ubuntu when I try to run it it gives me this error

```
"Unquoted fields do not allow \r or \n (line 2). (CSV::MalformedCSVError)"
```

this is how I open the file

```
 CSV.foreach("b2cStockXL.csv", :headers => true) do |csv_obj|
```

sample of csv

```
EAN,Artikel,Color,Size,Lager,Karton,Gender
4250484201561,9991,00/white,S,158,50,M
4250484201578,9990,00/white,M,354,50,M
```

any help would be great

Comment: Works fine for me. http://asciinema.org/a/5ofd8fs5xsi8e2xikty1x2soe

Comment: Me too. Ubuntu 15.10

Comment: thank you for looking, what I discovered is that if I remove the headers then the csv gets parsed. the problem must lay somewhere there

Comment: I found the issue, the headers row was ending in /n and the ones below were ending in /r. I just added /r to the header row

Answer (score 0):

The headers row was ending in /n and the ones below were ending in /r.
I just added /r to the header row